# Merge two survey datasets in R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, survey

I´m trying to merge two household surveys from the Dominican Republic, [Expenses](https://cdn.bancentral.gov.do/documents/estadisticas/encuesta-de-gastos-e-ingresos/documents/Cuadros_Gastos.xlsx?v=1689283267553) and [Income](https://cdn.bancentral.gov.do/documents/estadisticas/encuesta-de-gastos-e-ingresos/documents/Cuadros_Ingresos.xlsx?v=1689283267553).

The weight factor (`FACTOR_EXPANSION`) is supposed to represent population estimates which for the Dominican Republic is +10,000,000.

When I merge the two datasets, and sum the weight factor I get an extreme amount: 721,885,558.

How can I merge the two datasets and keep the sampling properties for `srvyr` package in R?

```
merge_income_expense <- merge(x=income, 
                              y=expense, 
                              by=c("TRIMESTRE", "REPLICA", "UPM", 
                                   "FACTOR_EXPANSION", "VIVIENDA", "HOGAR", 
                                   "ORDEN_REGION", "QUINTIL"),
                              all.x=TRUE)

> sum(income$FACTOR_EXPANSION)
 10299551

> sum(expense$FACTOR_EXPANSION)
 10299551

> sum(merge_income_expense$FACTOR_EXPANSION)
721885558
```

Comment: Btw same survey, just been split

Comment: Have you looked at the `merge_income_expense` to see what's happening?

Comment: (1) There are multiple worksheets per file, please specify. Further, they have "fancy headers" which means reading them in takes some more effort. When your question is not about "how to import", please don't make us download and figure out what you've already solved. It's usually easier (for us) when you provide raw data in your question by pasting the output from `dput(head(income,10))` (and `expense`) (or some number of columns/rows that we need, not always "all") into a [code block] in your question.

Comment: (2) *"keep the sampling properties"* doesn't make sense to me, what properties are being lost? (3) How do you know this is wrong? It might be informative for you to look at the number of rows in `income`, `expense`, and `merge_income_expense`; if the last is higher than the first (based on your `all.x=TRUE`), then it seems you have multiple rows matching, meaning your data is exploding. If this should never happen, it might be happening if you're missing a join-key, if there are duplicate data (in either), or a few other possibles.